# Converting String into Long for RGB() values

Tags: vba, excel, rgb

I am writing a macro that recognizes the RGB value of a cell and then passes it as an argument to conditional formatting. The only issue is that using below:

```
RGBcolor1 = "RGB(" & CInt("&H" & Right(HEXcolor1, 2)) & _
", " & CInt("&H" & Mid(HEXcolor1, 3, 2)) & _
", " & CInt("&H" & Left(HEXcolor1, 2)) & ")"
```

where:

```
HEXcolor1 = Right("000000" & Hex(Sheet1.[LowColour].Interior.Color), 6)
```

The RGB value is a string, whereas in order to pass it as `.Color`, I need it to be a Long `(Color = rgb(255, 0, 0))`.

I am aware solutions exist where using Debug window is recommended to retrieve `?rgb(255,0,0)`, however, I would like to automate the process. I tried `Clng()` as well as `.Evaluate()` but they did not work.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you trying to convert a Long to a Hex string and back to a Long?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to parse the string. You could use a regex or just make some simple replacements to isolate just the digits. For example:

```
strColor = "RGB(123, 0, 234)"
strColor = Replace(strColor, "RGB", "")
strColor = Replace(strColor,   "(", "")
strColor = Replace(strColor,   ")", "")
strColor = Replace(strColor,   " ", "")

Dim a As Variant, c As Long
a = Split(strColor, ",")
c = a(0) * &H10000 + a(1) * &H100 + a(2)

Range("A1").Interior.Color = c
```

Or, with a regex (you'll have to add a reference to the `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` library):

```
With New RegExp
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "[^\d,]"    ' Remove anything that's not a digit or comma
    Dim a As Variant, c As Long
    a = Split(.Replace(strColor, ""), ",")
    c = a(0) * &H10000 + a(1) * &H100 + a(2)
End If

Range("A1").Interior.Color = c
```

**Edit:**

Here's a quick but hacky way, using `Eval()` from the `Microsoft Script Control`:

```
With CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
    .Language = "VBScript"
    Range("A1").Interior.Color = .Eval(strColor)
End With
```

Comment: it's actually works for me only when i change your formula to that:
c = a(0)+ a(1) * &H100 + a(2) * &H10000 
any idea why? because this comment written one year ago and no one comment about it i guess it's my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it by using the val() function

```
Dim l as long
dim str as string

str = "111111"
l = val(str)
```

or

```
CLng(Val(str))
```

Comment: Hey Matthew, 

Thank you for advice! I tried both and they both end up being Empty. Using the watch I can see that RGBcolor1 is a String, with value "RGB(255, 0, 0)". However, l or CLng(Val(str)) both return Value of 0 if I pass RGBcolor1 as str. I am not entirely sure why is this happening as I expected that solution to work as well.

Comment: You will have to get the acutal values out of the string.  Take off the RGB( from the left and the ) from the right and then use the split function.